# Inlining or identical code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, inline, disassembly

How I can setup the compiler to generate identical code? For **example**:

```
inline bool iszero(int a)
{
    return (a == 0);
}

int main()
{
    int a = 4;

    if(a == 0) // First
        a = 5;

    if(iszero(a)) // Second
        a = 5;

    ///...
}
```

In debug mode (with inlining) disassembled code look like:

```
if(a == 0) // First
     a = 5;

bool temp; // Second
if(a == 0)
    temp = 0;
else
    temp = 1;

if(temp == 0)
    a = 5;
```

Why that happens?

Why this question has been asked? I need to debug my application with inlining functions (**for speed up debug**) and I do not want to **lose performance** in debug mode.

Comment: All compilers generate stupid code in debug mode, beause you told them not to "waste" any time making it better.

Comment: @BoPersson, so, Can I switch on optimizations only for inline fucntions?

Comment: No, that's not possible. You *can* debug in release mode though if you want, it's just *a lot* harder to follow the optimized code. Most of us just accept that debug mode is slow.

Comment: @BoPersson, ok. Is "incorrect" inlining is faster than function call?

Comment: We don't know. When compiling without optimizations, we tell the compiler not to spend any time figuring this out. The result will then be unpredictable performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compile in release mode, with full optimizations. The generated code will be the equivalent of:

```
int main()
{
}
```

There's no point in comparing code with no optimizations on, as there's no point in benchmarking with optimizations off.

Comment: Ahah, I know it =) I need to debug my applicatoin with inlining fuctions (**for speed up debug**) and I do not want to **lose performance** in debug mode.

Comment: @4Bytes: then you should do the other way around. Compile in release mode with debug info, and disable some optimizations that make it harder to debug (like inlining).